# File Sorter - fileNotFoundException

Tags: java, user-interface, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to create a program that reads a `File`, saves the content (words) in an `ArrayList`, sorts the `ArrayList`, and then writes the content of the *sorted* `ArrayList` back to the `File`.

I have no idea why, it keeps on giving me a `FileNotFoundException` or a `NullPointerException` (both are occurring, it's a bit wierd)...

Here's my code, if anyone can help that would be great.

Thanks.

By the way, the code contains four classes:

DriverClass, View(the GUI), ReadFile, and WriteFile.

You can ignore the comments, I just wrote those for myself - they're pretty obvious.  For "field.getText();" let's say the user enters  `C:\Users\Corecase\Desktop\test.txt`  I've tried doing `C:\\Users\\Corecase\\Desktop\\test.txt)` and that doesn't work either.

Thanks again!

```
public class DriverClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        View open= new View();
    }
}
```

//View

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class View implements ActionListener
{
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Sorter");
private JPanel mainPane = new JPanel();
private JPanel textPane = new JPanel();
private JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
private JButton sortButton = new JButton("Sort");
private JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter file path: ");
public JTextField field = new JTextField(25);

private Font f = new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.PLAIN, 20);


public View()
{
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(mainPane);

    mainPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    mainPane.setBackground(Color.gray);

    mainPane.add(textPane);
    mainPane.add(buttonPane);

    textPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    textPane.add(label);
    textPane.add(field);
    buttonPane.add(sortButton);
    field.setFont(f);
    sortButton.setFont(f);
    label.setFont(f);

    sortButton.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == sortButton)
    {
        ReadFile r = new ReadFile(field.getText());
        WriteFile w = new WriteFile(field.getText());

        r.openFile();
        r.readAndSortFile();
        r.closeFile();

        w.openFile();
        w.writeFile(r.getList());
        w.closeFile();
    }
}
}
```

//ReadFile

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFile extends View
{
private ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
private String fileName = new String();
private Scanner x;

public ReadFile(String address)
{
    fileName = address;
}
public void openFile()
{
    try
    {
        x = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        field.setText("Could not read file.");
    }
}

public void readAndSortFile()
{
    while(x.hasNext())
        words.add(x.next());

    sort();
}

public void closeFile()
{
    x.close();
}

public ArrayList<String> sort()
{
    String temp = "";

    for(int index = 0; index < words.size(); index++)
    {
        for(int inner = 0; inner < words.size(); inner++)
        {
            if((words.get(inner)).compareTo(words.get(inner+1)) > 0)
            {
                temp = words.get(inner);
                words.set(inner, words.get(inner + 1));
                words.set(inner + 1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}

public ArrayList<String> getList()
{
    return words;
}
}
```

//WriteFile

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class WriteFile extends View
{
private Formatter x;
private String fileName = new String();

public WriteFile(String address)
{
    fileName = address;
}

public void openFile()
{
    try
    {
        x = new Formatter(fileName);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        field.setText("Could not write to file.");
    }
}

public void writeFile(ArrayList<String> myWords)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < myWords.size(); index++)
        x.format("%s", myWords.get(index), "\n");//%s means string - in this case ONE string
}

public void closeFile()
{
    x.close();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between the 2 inputs you mentioned. Also, try forward slash ('/') instead of backslash.

Comment: Backslashes are OK on Windows. And escaping backslashes is only necessary for string literals, users in a console (or most type of input) don't have to escape them.

Comment: Could you reduce the question to the point in the code where there is the error instead of giving the whole program ? Stacktraces normally point the line of the exception.

Comment: You are saying that you are getting exceptions but you are not showing the stacktrace.

Comment: Awaiting stacktrace. suggestion : You are manually sorting your array List. You can use Collections.sort() method and comparator available in String class, this will reduce your code.

Comment: It's fixed guys, thanks for all the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your code. You are extending View to obtain a reference of the textField 'field'! and that is not the way to go. You should use Exception handling to do this simple task. Also you cannot read and write from/to a file simultaneously! so you need to separate the duties here. When you finish reading the file, close it and open it again with whatever writer you want to use. Final note: You could use FileChooser to obtain the path, and that saves you the need of checking valid inputs! If you want to do the hard way and force the user to input the path manually, you have to add the escape character '/', In your case, a valid path would be  `C:\\Users\\Corecase\\Desktop\\test.txt`

Change the following code in 'View.java'

```
    if (e.getSource() == sortButton)
    {
        ReadFile r;
        try
        {
            r = new ReadFile(field.getText());
            r.readAndSortFile();

            WriteFile w = new WriteFile(field.getText());
            w.writeFile(r.getList());

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
        {
            field.setText(e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

and change 'WriteFile.java' to

```
public class WriteFile
{
    private Formatter x;
    private String fileName;

    public WriteFile(String address) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        fileName = address;
        try
        {
            x = new Formatter(fileName);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not write to file.");
        }
    }

    public void writeFile(ArrayList<String> myWords)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < myWords.size(); index++)
            x.format("%s%s", myWords.get(index), System.lineSeparator());

        // now you are done writing so close the file.

        x.close();
    }
}
```

Change 'ReadFile.java' to

```
public class ReadFile
{
    private ArrayList<String> words;
    private String fileName;
    private Scanner x;

    public ReadFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        fileName = path;
        words = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            x = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File Doesn't exist in the place you specified.");
        }
    }


    public void readAndSortFile()
    {
        while (x.hasNext())
            words.add(x.next());
        Collections.sort(words);

        // Now you are done reading and sorting, so close the file.
        x.close();
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issue in your code:

- `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` are extending `View`, as per the constructor you will have multiple instances of `JFrame` opened, as you are making the frame visible in your constructor `frame.setVisible(true);`, `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` just need a reference of the `JTextField` which should be updated, just pass this as a parameter.
- Your `sort` will definitely throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for this line

  if ((words.get(inner)).compareTo(words.get(inner + 1)) > 0) {

  This line won't work when it reaches the last index, why not use simple `Collections.sort(words);`
- You don't have a check if user has entered path or not, if nothing is entered, you will get `NullPointerException` in your `ReadFile`, ideally if file is not found i.e. your scanner is null, don't proceed further. Currently you are showing an error message but your code doesn't stop there, it still tries to read and sort file which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried your example and debugged it. I used c:\\dir\\file.text as parameter to the GUI and the file is read properly, so it is not there your problem. The exception i was getting was coming  from this code:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < words.size(); index++) {
        for (int inner = 0; inner < words.size(); inner++) {
            if ((words.get(inner)).compareTo(words.get(inner + 1)) > 0) {
                temp = words.get(inner);
                words.set(inner, words.get(inner + 1));
                words.set(inner + 1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundException` means that the file was not found.

`NullPointerException` means you tried to dereference a null pointer.

If that doesn't answer your question I don't know what does. StackOverflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: You're absolutely right; StackOverflow is NOT a debugging service - it is a service where people help each other to understand/solve problems.